# Is it possible to add a reference to the Microsoft Office DLL's in a C# MVC3 project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, vba, ms-office

I don't know if this is possible, but I'd like to add a program reference to MS office in my MVC3 project.

More specifically, I'd like to be able to programmatically create edit and send dynamically generated office documents using the built-in Office objects.  As compared to using a third party FOSS API, I'd prefer to use the direct MS version of the objects because I've got a lot of VBA know how and think that working directly with the MS-Office "guts" will be a lot easier for me.

Assuming office is properly installed on the server this runs on, I should be able to reference and script the Office application directly from within a C# MVC right?

I figure I'm probably looking for 3 things

- the `using Microsoft.Office;` directive for C#
- the name of the DLL that I must register `regsvr32 <pathname>/<officeDLLname>.dll`
- the way I go about adding the reference to my MVC3 project in visual studio

Unless there is anything else I'm missing, I'd expect that from there I'd be able to create a new Excel object and have the web server build it.

```
Excel objXL = new Microsoft.Office.Excel();
objXL.<do stuff>;
objXL.Save(<bla bla bla>);
' profit!
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to add a reference to the dll as well and you also need office installed on the server as the office com components actually run the office programs to get there functionality.

Comment: No, don't do it - the office objects [aren't built for non-interactive use](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757). Instead there's plenty of libraries available for e.g. [creating Excel files from C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)

Comment: Thanks @Rup the second half of the http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757 article has what I'm looking for `Alternatives to server-side Automation`

Answer (score 0):

you will need to give aspnet/network identity user a permissions to add/edit documents. other than that, why not?

Comment: Because "Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment." [KB257757](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)

Comment: I second Rup on this stay away!

Comment: Run office on server side is not a good idea. I am using ASPOSE.Words to handle word and pdf generation and my client is very happy.